# Python project organization from sub-directories

Tags: python

I have a number of scripts with logical groups.

```
.
|_ database
|  |_ db.txt
|  |_ make_db.py
|
|_ accessory
|  |_ util.py
|
|_ explore_one_way
|  |_ script1.py
|
|_ explore_a_second_way
   |_ script2.py
```

How do I access, say, util.py from script1.py?  Is there another way than adding to sys.path or is that the most pythonic?

Update:  This is relatively painless.  I added `__init__.py` to the accessory directory and can then do:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '..')
from proj import util
```

or

```
from proj.util import some_symbol
```

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- add `sys.path` ((-) not very pythonic vs (+) easy)
- use `soft links` ((-) sometimes gives issues with docker vs (+) you can link to directories). Soft links are a files that are *like* copies of other files, but not real copies (like a shallow copy). There's always only one copy of the file ever.
- use `hard links` ((-) need to link every file, no directories vs (+) no docker issues). Hard links are actual copies that sync their clones if you change either one of them.

I recommend soft links if you don't like `__init__.py` and `sys.path`!

Comment: I was afraid of that.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should create empty `__init__.py` file each folder. Then add the top of your `script1.py` file as below.

```
import sys 
sys.path.insert(0, ".")

from accessory import util.py
```

Check out [more](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

Comment: I think you want ".."

Answer (score 0):

`.
|_ database
|  |_ db.txt
|  |_ make_db.py
|
|_ accessory
|  |_ util.py
|  |_ __init__.py
|
|_ explore_one_way
|  |_ script1.py
|
|_ explore_a_second_way
   |_ script2.py`

Make **accessory** a python package by adding **init**.py to it.
Then do this

```
from accessory import util
```

Comment: This raises ImportError.

Comment: Not sure if you are maintaining the same directory structure. But try  ```from .accessory import util```